# How to create a task in Salesforce using curl?

Tags: api, curl, salesforce, task

Which URL I should send the request to? (I already have my instance, I need the path). I have the oauth token, and I have the data.
Thanks!
H

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I've got it:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer <oauth token>' \
     https://<your instance url>/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Task
```